# Crear niveles de usuario en sistema de login usando sesiones

Tags: php, mysqli

Quisiera poder establecer niveles de usuario (administrador y usuario normal) usando las sesiones, ya tengo en mi tabla de usuarios el nivel de la cuenta ahora quisiera validar su entrada pero no se como obtener el nivel de la tabla
uso lo siguiente:

CONECTARSE.php

```
          <?php
   session_start();    
   if (isset($_POST['aceptar'])) {

      require_once 'conexion.php';

      $usuario =   $_POST['txtusuario'];
      $contrasena =$_POST['txtcontrasena'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?";

   $statement=$conexion->prepare($sql);
   $statement->bind_param('ss',$usuario, $contrasena);
   $statement->execute();
   $statement->store_result();


    if ($statement->num_rows===0) { 
     echo "Verifique sus datos";

   } else {

      $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nivel_id from usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'") or die($conexion->error);
      $stmt->execute() or die($conexion->error);
      $stmt->store_result();
      $numfilas=$stmt->num_rows;
      echo $numfilas;
      $stmt->bind_result($nivel_id);
      while ($stmt->fetch())
      {
      $nivel=$nivel_id;
      echo $nivel;
      }
         $_SESSION['nivel']=$nivel;
         $_SESSION['conectado']=true; //esta conectado//
         $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
         $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
         $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (5 * 60);

        if ($nivel==1){
              header ("location: unidades/menu_unidades.php");
               }
              elseif ($nivel==4){
              header ("location: administrador/menu_administrador.php");
      }

         }
   }

   ?>
```

Pagina del Administrador

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['conectado'] ) && $_SESSION['conectado'] == true && $_SESSION['nivel']==2) {
if()
include 'conexion.php';
include 'encabezado.php';
echo "Conectado como:" . $_SESSION['usuario'];
} else {
echo "Esta pagina es solo para usuarios registrados y administradores.<br>";
header ("location: index.php");   
exit;
}
$now = time();
if($now > $_SESSION['expira']) {
session_destroy();
echo "Su sesion a terminado">
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <title>Sistema Automatizado de Orden de Medida Disciplinaria</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="387" border="0" align="center">
         <tr>
            <td width="381">
               <p align="center" class="style4">Menu Principal</p>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <table width="578" height="158" border="1" align="center" bgcolor="#000099">
         <tr>
            <td width="568">
               <table width="600" border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                  <tr>
                     <td width="200" height="200">
                        <a title="ico_usu" href="menu_usuario_administradores.php">
                           <center><img width="150" height="150" src="iconos/ico_usu.jpg" alt="USUARIO" /></center>
                        </a>
                        <center>UNIDADES</center>
                     </td>
                     <td width="200" height="200">
                        <a title="ico_lup" href="http://www.ejercito.mil.ve/justicia/correccion/hoja_sancion/consultageneral_usu3.php">
                           <center><img width="150" height="150" src="iconos/ico_lup.jpg" alt="CONSULTAR" /></center>
                        </a>
                        <center>USUARIOS</center>
                     </td>
                     <td width="200" height="200">
                        <a title="ico_gra" href="#">
                           <center><img width="150" height="150" src="iconos/ico_gra.jpg" alt="GRAFICOS" /></center>
                        </a>
                        <center>CONSULTAS</center>
                     </td>
                     <td width="200" height="200">
                        <a title="ico_gen" href="http://www.ejercito.mil.ve/justicia/correccion/hoja_sancion/index3.php">
                           <center><img width="150" height="150" src="iconos/ico_gen.jpg" alt="GENERAR" /></center>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="200" border="0" align="center">

         <tr>
                <td><a href="desconectarse.php"><img src="imagenes/Salir.jpg" width="67" height="69" border="0" /></a></td>

                   <td>
               <div align="center"><strong>Salir</strong></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in >C:\wamp\www\Sistema Automatizado OMD\conectarse.php on line 22

NOTA ADICIONAL: uso php 5.2.0 y los header que estan comentados me dan error (dicen que ya se hizo el output), alguna solucion?

Comment: el fallo esta en `$statement->nivel`.. el fallo de los headers es porque no puedes tener nada antes que se envie... es decir en tu ejemplo el echo

Comment: yo quiero que se pase a alguno de esos dos php validando su nivel, como obtengo el nivel? no se como utilizar los statement muy bien

Comment: eso lo tienes que saber tu :) hay un campo de nivel en la BD o lo creas `on the fly`

Comment: ahi un campo creado, pero donde agrego nivel?

Comment: en el bind_param?

Comment: bueno... entiendo tu desesperación... pero te recomiendo de verdad y con todo el corazón... (ya que he visto algunas preguntas ya sobre esto)... que estudies un poco como funciona las consultas y como recibir los valores y tal con mysqli o PDO...no es difícil... ej. `mysqli_real_escape_string ` no necesitas ya que estas usando sentencias preparadas...

Comment: gracias por tu consejo :) ya lo reviso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54690/discussion-between-victor-a-and-aldanux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lei sobre las sentencias preparadas (sugerencia de @aldanux) y quedo asi:

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    if (isset($_POST['aceptar'])) {

       require_once 'conexion.php';

       $usuario =   $_POST['txtusuario'];
       $contrasena =$_POST['txtcontrasena'];

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?";

    $statement=$conexion->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('ss',$usuario, $contrasena);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();


     if ($statement->num_rows===0) { 
      echo "Verifique sus datos";

    } else {

       $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nivel_id from usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'") or die($conexion->error);
       $stmt->execute() or die($conexion->error);
       $stmt->store_result();
       $numfilas=$stmt->num_rows;
       //echo $numfilas;
       $stmt->bind_result($nivel_id);
       while ($stmt->fetch())
       {
       $nivel=$nivel_id;
       //echo $nivel;
       }
          $_SESSION['nivel']=$nivel;
          $_SESSION['conectado']=true; //esta conectado//
          $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
          $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
          $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (5 * 60);

         if ($nivel==1){
                header("location: menu_unidades.php");
                }
               elseif ($nivel==2){
                header("location:menu_administradores.php");
       }

          }
    }
    ?>
```

Comparto una guia con ejemplos para consultar, modificar, borrar y actualizar datos con sentencias preparadas y mysqli:

tabla.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pruebas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edad` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `fechanac` date NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

conexion.php

```
<?php
    //////////////////////////
    // conexion.php
    //////////////////////////

    // Datos configuración de la conexión al Servidor MySQL.

    $nombrebase="basedatos";
    $usuario="usuario";
    $servidor="localhost";

    $password="password";
    //////////////////////////////////////

    // Hacemos la conexión al servidor de MySQL utilizando la clase mysqli
    // Utilizamos la @ antes de crear el objeto, ya que si da error,
    // queremos mostrarlo con un mensaje personalizado.

    $mysqli=@new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$nombrebase);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    {
        die ("Error en conexión base datos: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

altas.php

```
<?php
// Crear el formulario para recoger datos de los usuarios.

// Si estamos recibiendo datos del formulario...
// Insertamos esos datos en la tabla.

if ( isset($_POST['nombre']) && $_POST['nombre']!=""   )
{
    // Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
    require("conexion.php");

    // Preparamos la instrucción SQL. Prepare nos devuelve un objeto de la clase mysqli_stmt
// o false si hay un error.
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into pruebas (nombre,apellidos,edad,fechanac,password) 
values(?,?,?,?,?)") or die($mysqli->error);

    // Enlazamos los parámetros (5 cadenas de texto 's')
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$_POST['nombre'],$_POST['apellidos'],$_POST['edad'],$_POST['fechanac'],
$_POST['password']);

    // Ejecutamos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error);

    // Mostramos el mensaje x filas insertadas correctamente.
    printf("%d fila insertada correctamente.\n",$stmt->affected_rows);

    // Cerramos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt -> close();

    // Cerramos la conexión.
    $mysqli->close();
}
else
{
// En otro caso mostramos el formulario de altas.
?>
    <h2> Alta de Usuarios </h2>

    <form name="formulario" method="post">
    Nombre: <input name="nombre" type="text"/><br/>
    Apellidos: <input name="apellidos" type="text"/><br/>
    Edad: <input name="edad" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" /><br/>
    Fecha Nacimiento: <input name="fechanac" type="text"/><br/>
    Password: <input name="password" type="password"/><br/>
    <input type="reset" value="Limpiar"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Alta Usuario"/><br/>
    </form>

<?php
}
?>
```

bajas.php

```
<?php
// Conectamos a la base de datos
require("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!="-1")
{
    // Construimos la sentencia de borrado SQL.
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("delete from pruebas where id=?") or die($mysqli->error);

    // Enlazamos los parámetros (1 entero 'i')
    // http://es2.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

    $stmt->bind_param("i",$_POST['id']);

    // Ejecutamos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error);

    // Mostramos mensaje 
    echo "Registro borrado correctamente";

    // Cerramos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt->close();
}
?>

<h2> Borrado de registros </h2>
<form name="formulario" method="post">
<select name="id">
<option value="-1">Seleccione registro</option>
<?php
    // Cubrimos dinámicamente el formulario.

    // Construimos la sentencia de select SQL
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id,nombre,apellidos from pruebas") or die($mysqli->error);

    // No tenemos ningún parámetro a enlazar, así que..
    // ejecutamos la sentencia preparada directamente
    $stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error);

    // Si es una consulta de select almacenamos el resultado con el método store_result() del objeto $stmt.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Número de filas obtenidas, si fuera necesario.
    // $numfilas=$stmt->num_rows;

    // Vinculamos unas variables a los resultados con el método bind_result() de stmt,
    // antes de llamar al método fetch() de stmt
    $stmt->bind_result($campoid, $camponombre, $campoapellidos);

    // Recorremos el recordset:
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $cadena=sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s %s</option>",$campoid,$camponombre,$campoapellidos);
        echo $cadena;
    }

    // Liberamos el resultado.
    $stmt-> free_result();

    // Cerramos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt->close();

    // Cerramos conexión
    $mysqli->close();
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Borrar Registro"/>
</form>
```

modificaciones.php

```
<?php
// Conectamos a la base de datos.
require("conexion.php");

// Si recibimos datos formulario de selección.
if (isset($_POST['selectid']) && $_POST['selectid']!=-1)
{
    // Preparamos la consulta SQL
    $stmt= $mysqli->prepare("select id,nombre,apellidos,edad from pruebas where id=?") 
or die($mysqli->error());

    // Enlazamos los parámetros (1 entero 'i')
    // http://es2.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
    // Vinculamos los parámetros a la consulta
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$_POST['selectid']);

    // Ejecutamos la consulta preparada.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Si es una consulta de select almacenamos el resultado.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Vinculamos unas variables a los resultados con el método bind_result() de stmt,
    // antes de llamar al método fetch() de stmt
    $stmt->bind_result($elid, $elnombre, $losapellidos, $laedad);

    // Leemos la primera fila de ese recordset
    // Los datos que hemos leído estará en las variables que hemos vinculado antes.
    $stmt->fetch();

    // Construimos el formulario y ponemos los datos
    // de ese usuario en los campos.
?>
    <!-- Formulario de altas -->
    <h2>Edición de Usuario</h2>

    <form name="formulario" method="post">
    Nombre: <input name="nombre" type="text" value="<?php echo $elnombre ?>"/><br/>
    Apellidos: <input name="apellidos" type="text" value="<?php echo $losapellidos ?>"/><br/>
    Edad: <input name="edad" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo $laedad ?>"/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $elid ?>"/>

    <input type="reset" value="resetear"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Actualizar"/><br/>
    </form>

<?php
}
// Si recibimos datos del formulario de edición...
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    // Preparamos la consulta SQL
    $stmt= $mysqli->prepare("update pruebas set nombre=?,apellidos=?,edad=? where id=?");

    // Enlazamos los parámetros (3 string:'s' y 1 entero:'i')
    // http://es2.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi",$_POST['nombre'],$_POST['apellidos'],$_POST['edad'],$_POST['id']);

    // Ejecutamos consulta de update.
    $stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error());

    // Cerramos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt -> close();

    // Mostramos mensaje de OK.
    echo "Actualización correcta de los datos del usuario: {$_POST['nombre']} ";
}
?>
<h2> Actualización de Registros</h2>
<form name="formulario" method="post">
<select name="selectid">
<option value="-1">Seleccione registro</option>
<?php
    // Cubrimos dinámicamente el formulario.

    // Construimos la sentencia de select SQL
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id,nombre,apellidos from pruebas") or die($mysqli->error);

    // No tenemos ningún parámetro a enlazar, así que..
    // ejecutamos la sentencia preparada directamente
    $stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error);

    // Si es una consulta de select almacenamos el resultado con el método store_result() del objeto $stmt.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Número de filas obtenidas, si fuera necesario.
    // $numfilas=$stmt->num_rows;

    // Vinculamos unas variables a los resultados con el método bind_result() de stmt,
    // antes de llamar al método fetch() de stmt
    $stmt->bind_result($campoid, $camponombre, $campoapellidos);

    // Recorremos el recordset:
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $cadena=sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s %s</option>",$campoid,$camponombre,$campoapellidos);
        echo $cadena;
    }

    // Liberamos el resultado.
    $stmt-> free_result();

    // Cerramos la conexión.
    $mysqli->close();
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Seleccionar"/>
</form>
```

consultas.php

```
<?php
    // Conectarse a la base de datos.
    require("conexion.php");

    // Preparamos la consulta.
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nombre,apellidos,edad from pruebas") or die($mysqli->error);

    // Ejecutamos la consulta preparada.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Si es una consulta de select almacenamos el resultado.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Número de filas obtenidas en $stmt->num_rows
    echo "Se han encontrado $stmt->num_rows registros.<br/><br/>";

    // Vinculamos unas variables a los resultados con el método bind_result() de stmt,
    // antes de llamar al método fetch() de stmt
    $stmt->bind_result($elnombre, $losapellidos, $laedad);

    // Recorremos el recordset.
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellidos</th> <th>Edad</th></tr>";

    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$elnombre."</td><td>".$losapellidos."</td><td>".$laedad."</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    // Liberamos el espacio que ocupa ese resultado en memoria.
    $stmt -> free_result();

    // Cerramos la conexión con el servidor mysql.
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema viene siendo $statement. Cuando se ejecuta la consulta la trabajas como un objeto pero en verdad es un arreglo ya q una consulta puede devolver mas de un row aunque este no el caso debido a la consulta q haces, pero php no lo sabe y te devuelve un arreglo q nada mas tiene un objeto por eso te da error prueba haciendo esto:
$statement[0]->nivel;

Comment: Cannot use object of type mysqli_stmt as array in C:\wamp\www\Sistema Automatizado OMD\conectarse.php on line 21

con esa linea me da error

Comment: prueba esto: while($row = $statement->fetch_array()){
  $nivel=$row['nivel']; //Columna nivel
}

Comment: donde lo coloco?

Comment: donde pones $nivel=$statement->nivel; por supuesto declara $nivel antes de poner el while

Comment: ya subi editado, me da error

Comment: ya modifique el codigo y funciona el obtenr el valor pero no redirecciona

Comment: y te devuelve el nivel que es

Comment: sip aunque tuve que hacer doble sentencia porque no creo que se pueda hacer ambas cosas en la primera sentencia

Comment: y no te entra a ninguno de los if ? De ser prueba poniedolo asi '1' y '2'

Comment: me refiero a: statement y stmt, que son dos sentencias separadas, no supe hacer que con solo statement pudiera hacer ambas cosas